# How often are Debian packages imported into Ubuntu during development?

Tags: debian

I know that Ubuntu imports its packages from Debian unstable during its development phase of a new distribution release. This happens until the DebianImportFreeze starts. I am trying to find documentation on how often packages are synched from Debian during the regular development period. Does this happens daily? Are there any public logs on which packages were imported?

Comment: Merges from Debian are ongoing and occur most workdays. See https://merges.ubuntu.com/ for lots and lots of information and status updates.